# Flow variable not working correct for DB select query

Tags: sql, mule

I am facing one Strange issue ... My Mule flow is as follow :-

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
 <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertQuery" value="INSERT INTO getData(ID,NAME,AGE,DESIGNATION)VALUES(#[flowVars['id']],#[flowVars['name']],#[flowVars['age']],#[flowVars['designation']])"/> 

<jdbc-ee:query key="RetriveQuery" value="Select * from getData where ID=#[flowVars['id']] "/>
</jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="MuleDbInsertFlow1" doc:name="MuleDbInsertFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<cxf:jaxws-service service="MainData" serviceClass="com.vertu.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData"  doc:name="SOAPWithHeader" />
<component class="com.vertu.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/>
 <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>

  <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction'] contains 'retrieveDataOperation']">
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
        <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[xpath('//id').text]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <logger message="ID from req #[flowVars['id']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_Global" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>  

       <choice doc:name="Choice">
              <when expression="#[message.payload.isEmpty()]">
                 <processor-chain>
                  <!-- Data not exists .. We cannot display -->             
                   <logger message="No records found in Database !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                  </processor-chain>
                </when>
                  <otherwise>
                   <processor-chain>
                      <!-- Data  exists .. We cannotdisplay -->   
                    <logger message="The Data retrieved from the Database" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                   </processor-chain>
                   </otherwise>
               </choice>
```

Now the issue is whenever I use the query **RetriveQuery**:- `Select * from getData where ID=#[flowVars['id']]`

It goes to the choice block where the logger shows **No records found in Database !!!** .. But you can see I placed a logger before call the SQL query by DB outbound

`<logger message="ID from req #[flowVars['id']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_Global" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>`

which prints `#[flowVars['id']]` and I am successfully getting the value ..
But I don't know why it is going to the  `<when expression="#[message.payload.isEmpty()]">`block ...

If I use the following in **RetriveQuery** : `Select * from getData where ID=22` 
Then it's successfully getting the value of ID in the query ..
Please let me know why it's not getting the  value in SQL query if I use a **flowVars** .. 
It's executing successfully for insert and update query but not for Select ..

**Pls note :-** here the value of ID in Select * from getData where ID is integer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange.

Try cleaning and re-building the project: the version that's running is maybe not using the latest config.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was a strange and I found cleaning and re building the project in studio as David suggested worked .. may be there was an issue in picking up the latest config and reflecting in the proect